# Do many Robocopy threads harm conventional hard disks?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, robocopy, lifespan

I spent some hours with creating a batch file to run a save from different servers onto a dedicated backup server, using Robocopy. All participating machines have an Intel i7 CPU with 4 cores. Due to hyperthreading, I was expecting an /MT setting of 8 performing best, and well, so it was (mm:ss):

```
 1 thread:  59:19
 2 threads: 39:12
 4 threads: 29:13
 8 threads: 24:36
16 threads: 24:19
32 threads: 24:27
```

(These times were for 147,314 files in 4,110 folders, totalling 67 GB.)

However, when testing beyond 8 threads, I noticed, that disk accesses were much more frequent and started to wonder, if the additional strain possibly would harm the disks and adversely affect their lifetimes.

Taking it further, I am not sure, that I should proceed even with 8 threads, as the frequency of the blinkenlights begin to make me quite nervous.

So the question is: do more Robocopy threads harm the harddisks (conventional 4 x 4TB platters in a JBOD case, managed as a single mirrored and striped disk by Microsoft's Storage Space under Win 8.1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most stressful thing you can do to a hard drive is spin it up.

So if you have aggressive power management enabled on the drive, and it is spinning up and down constantly in response to requests, it may fail prematurely.

Otherwise, the platter is always spinning while a disk is on.

Modern drive heads (not the platter) are controlled by a voice-coil, e.g. magnetism moves them.  So there is not a lot of friction in play.  While anything mechanical can fail, the actual drive head failing by means other than stiction (which generally occurs as a manufacturing defect that often happens soon after the drive is first used) is incredibly rare.

The amount of reads/writes you do to a spinning disk will really not affect its lifetime as long as Windows isn't spinning down the disk and making it spin back up constantly.

Comment: Thank you, so I will continue to use /MT:8. Allow a follow-up question, though: the backup machine is designed so, that on power-up the script starts, connects to the machines in question, does the saves, and shuts down itself when done. This is done once daily, on special request twice, say 500 times a year. Is this already considered stressful?